# can't run docker image of jhipster webapp

Tags: postgresql, docker, jhipster

I have a **jhipster** monolithic web app with **postgress** database. I built a docker image using

```
./gradlew bootRepackage -Pprod buildDocker
```

Now when I try to run the image using docker run , it fails with following error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
```

I tried few things like, but still get the same error:

```
docker create -v /var/lib/postgresql/data --name spring_app_data postgres:9.5.1

docker run --volumes-from spring_app_data --name spring_app_pg -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -P postgres:9.5.1

docker run -it --link spring_app_pg:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgres'

docker run --name spring_app_container --link spring_app_pg:spring_app_pg -p 8080:8080 -d wmd_server_pg
```

Any suggestions on how to run the docker image for a webapp with PostgreSQL. BTW I get same kind of error when I use mongodb.

Comment: This looks like you have not configured either postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf to accept a connection from your IP and user account.

Comment: JHipster also generates a Docker Compose file with both your app and your database already configured, so that you don't have to do this manual configuration

Comment: Thanks @JulienDubois for the response. As you said , using "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up" brings up spring boot and database.
But this means that the users need access to the source (i.e src/main/docker folder). 
I want to give the image to someone who does not have access to the source. For this use case I thought I could give them the docker image with which they can run the complete web app. In this case wouldn't I need to do the above manual configuration steps? Is there a easier/better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your example commands your database won't be accessible as `localhost` from the app, it will be via the named container. Configure your apps database connection to use `spring_app_pg:5432`.

Also, don't use links. Use a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#user-defined-networks), most likely a bridge is all you will need.

```
docker network create my_app
docker run --net=my_app --name=spring_app_pg <dbimage>
docker run --net=my_app --name=spring_app_container <appimage>
```

That should give you the same result as your linked setup.